# don't render a container from the application layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, render

Hello I'm very new in ruby on rails, I need to exclude (no render) a container that is in the application layout (base) and it's causing me a lot trouble. I'm working on my sign layout _new_web.html.erb and is including everything from the application layout, I just need to exclude a container, I tried a lot things, I dont find the devise controller (sign in controller), I only see the application controller and I can't do anything to get it right.I whish I could do it in the same _new_web.html.erb layout. I find this code and looks good but I don't know what is the current_page? and the root path, my url is /users/sign_in -> _new_web.html.erb, I can't find in the routes where the root path of this layout.

```
<% if current_page?(root_path) %>
   <%= render 'layouts/home_header' %>
<% else %>
   <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks !!!

Comment: add parameter `layout: false` in your *render*

Comment: @maguri thanks, but it disable all the layout, I just want to render all the layout but without a specific container, any help?

Answer (score 0):

I should rename the layouts to `shared/_<name>.html.erb` folder.

In your `layouts/_application.html.erb` do the following:

```
<% if current_page?(root_path) %>
  <%= render 'shared/_home_header' %>
<% else %>
  <%= render 'shared/_header' %>
<% end %>
```

tree:

```
- views
 |- layouts/application.html.erb
 |- shared/
 | |- _header.html.erb
 | |- _home_header.html.erb
```

To generate your own **devise controller** you should run:

```
rails generate devise:controllers users
```